# When I press back on my program i get a blank screen

Tags: java, android

After getting to the chapter3_1.xml page which pulls up fine when i press my phones back key and it takes me to the previous button. press back again and there's a blank page that isn't supposed to be there. press back again and you get to the original button. no errors no crashes.

Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".SubMenu1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference.SUBMENU1" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Chapter3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference.CHAPTER3" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Chapter3_1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference.CHAPTER3_1" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>

 </manifest>
```

MainMenu.java

```
 package com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainMenu extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnChpt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChpt3);
    btnChpt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference.CHAPTER3"));
        }
    });
 }
 }
```

SubMenu1.java

```
 package com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class SubMenu1 extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chapter3);

    Button btnChpt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChpt3_1);
    btnChpt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference.CHAPTER3_1"));
        }
    });
 }

 }
```

Chapter3.java

```
 package com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Chapter3 extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(new Intent("com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference.SUBMENU1"));
 }

 }
```

Chapter3_1.java

```
 package com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Chapter3_1 extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chapter3_1);
 }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.th3ramr0d.ar670_1quickreference.MainActivity" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChpt3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chapter 3" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

chapter3.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChpt3_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="fuckmylife" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

chapter3_1.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is the content of chapter 3_1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using fragment in your application.
And when you pushing the fragment you'r are adding it to back stack thats why when you press back button it will show a blank screen which is the framelayout on which you are showing the fragment view.
Refer the [link :-](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

[Fragmnet manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)

Comment: I think im going to stick to the youtube tutorials instead of trying to learn a little bit and jump into full fledge projects. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, in activity you should set parent like this:

```
  android:parentActivityName="com.some.myproject.ParentActivityToThisActivity"
```

But it can not working with API 14, API 15 should be used or newest.

Comment: so basically use that to set each activity to its appropriate parent?

Comment: In short words - yes. I am using method like this and it working. As I rememeber, I had alert about problem with api 14, but in my current project I am using min API 15. Reason can be different in your app, just guessing, but it should help.